# How to join two pandas dataframes based on a date in df1 being >= date in df2

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a large data frame with key IDs, states, start dates and other characteristics.  I have another data frame with states, a start date and a "1" to signify a flag.

I want to join the two, based on the state and the date in df1 being greater than or equal to the date in df2.

Take the example below.  `df1` is the table of states, start dates, and a 1 for a flag.  `df2` is a dataframe that needs those flags `if` the date in df2 is `>=` the date in `df1`.  The end result is `df3`.  The only observations get the flag whose states match and dates are `>=` the original dates.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'date':['2020-01-01', '2020-02-15', '2020-02-04','2020-03-17',
                 '2020-06-15'],
         'state':['AL','FL','MD','NC','SC'],
         'flag': [1,1,1,1,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

dict2 = {'state': ['AL','FL','MD','NC','SC'],
         'keyid': ['001','002','003','004','005'],
         'start_date':['2020-02-01', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-30','2020-05-18',
                       '2020-05-16']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_date'])

df3 = df2
df3['flag'] = [0,1,1,0,1]
```

How do I get to df3 programmatically?  My actual `df1` has a row for each state.  My actual `df2` has over a million observations with different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for merge by greater or equal datetimes by parameter `direction='forward'`:

> A “forward” search selects the first row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is greater than or equal to the left’s key.

```
df2['need'] = [0,1,1,0,1]

df1 = df1.sort_values('date')
df2 = df2.sort_values('start_date')

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, 
                   df1, 
                   left_on='start_date', 
                   right_on='date', 
                   by='state',
                   direction='forward')


df['flag'] = df['flag'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)

  state keyid start_date  need       date  flag
0    FL   002 2020-01-15     1 2020-02-15     1
1    MD   003 2020-01-30     1 2020-02-04     1
2    AL   001 2020-02-01     0        NaT     0
3    SC   005 2020-05-16     1 2020-06-15     1
4    NC   004 2020-05-18     0        NaT     0
```

You can also `rename` column for avoid appending in output `DataFrame`:

```
df2['need'] = [0,1,1,0,1]

df1 = df1.sort_values('date')
df2 = df2.sort_values('start_date')

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, 
                   df1.rename(columns={'date':'start_date'}), 
                   on='start_date', 
                   by='state',
                   direction='forward')

df['flag'] = df['flag'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
  state keyid start_date  need  flag
0    FL   002 2020-01-15     1     1
1    MD   003 2020-01-30     1     1
2    AL   001 2020-02-01     0     0
3    SC   005 2020-05-16     1     1
4    NC   004 2020-05-18     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [29]: import numpy as np

In [30]: df3 = df2.merge(df1)[['state', 'keyid', 'start_date', 'date']]

In [31]: df3['flag'] = np.where(df3['start_date'].ge(df3['date']), 0, 1)

In [33]: df3.drop('date', 1, inplace=True)

In [34]: df3
Out[34]: 
  state keyid start_date  flag
0    AL   001 2020-02-01     0
1    FL   002 2020-01-15     1
2    MD   003 2020-01-30     1
3    NC   004 2020-05-18     0
4    SC   005 2020-05-16     1
```